# ExpressJS sessions with MySQL data store not working

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to NodeJS and also ExpressJS and am attempting to set up session functionality with a MySQL data store. I have followed the documentation as far as how to invoke it, but after I have run the commands, req.session is undefined. I have verified that I have an active connection to the MySQL database and a common cookie secret when I instantiate the cookie, and the session. I'm not getting any errors, but here is the console debug output...

> terminal$ clear;DEBUG=express-mysql-session* npm start
>
> node-app@0.0.0 start node_app
>
> node ./bin/www
>
> GET /login 200 7.458 ms - 249
>
> express-mysql-session:log Creating session store +0ms
>
> express-mysql-session:log Setting default options +3ms
>
> POST /login 200 40.744 ms - 47
>
> express-mysql-session:log Setting expiration interval: 900000ms +7ms
>
> express-mysql-session:log Clearing expiration interval +0ms`

I tried enabling debugging when running this...

`var pool = mysql.createPool(options);`

and I didn't see a query even attempting to run to add the session to the session table.

Here is my application flow:
in my main.js file, I catch all requests at the top and check for a valid session, if I don't find one, I show the login form.

```
app.get('/*',function(req, res){ 
if (!req.session) {
    var login = require('../js/login_functions');
    res.send( login.getLoginForm() );
}});
```

The login form posts to /login where I verify that the username/password validates and then I create a session with a required session.js file. Here is the code in session.js

```
var config = require('../admin/config');
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
var db = require('../js/database');
var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

module.exports = {
    createSession: function( req, callback ){
        db.getConnection( function( connection ){           
            var session_store_options = {
                checkExpirationInterval: 900000,// How frequently expired sessions will be cleared; milliseconds. 
                expiration: config.SESS_MAX_AGE,// 10 hours session expiration
                createDatabaseTable: false,
                connectionLimit: config.DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT, 
                schema: {
                    tableName: config.SESS_TABLE_NAME,
                    columnNames: {
                        session_id: 'session_id',
                        expires: 'expires',
                        data: 'user_data'
                    }
                }
            };
            
            var session_options = {
                key: config.SESS_COOKIE_NAME,
                secret: config.SESS_SECRET,
                store: new MySQLStore(session_store_options, connection),
                cookie: { maxAge: config.SESS_MAX_AGE },
                genid: function(req) {
                    return genuuid() // use UUID for session ID
                },
                rolling: true,
                resave: false,
                saveUninitialized: false,
            };

            if( config.ENV.toLowerCase() === 'prod' ){
                session_options.cookie.secure = true;
            }
            app.use( session( session_options ) );
            if( config.DEBUG ){
                console.log( req.session );
            }
            callback( session );
        });
    }
};
```

When I run the console.log( req.session ) at the bottom of the above, it outputs undefined. Am I missing a step to invoke the cookie and db store session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the session was not being invoked and I needed to manually invoke it by breaking up session invocation like this

```
sess = session_( session_options );
sess( req, res, function(err){ if(err) console.log( 'error:', err ); } );
app.use( sess );
```

rather than this

```
app.use( session( session_options ) );
```